# Disable backbutton click in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to disable back button press so the app does not close as my app is a single page app..

i read that you need to wait for deviceready event, and if i look at the console im receiving that event. (BUT from another location i suspect its hidden in the templated and cant find out how to apply my functions to that)
    Received Event: deviceready

problem is that im just not receiving anything and my app just closes when the i press the back button. and i think im receiving the deviceready from somewhere else build in by adobe in the template i used for my app..

so none of the functions are getting fired thats why i tend to believe i need to place this somewhere else

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
     function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    alert('gege');
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    alert('gege');
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
alert('backbuttonpressed');
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
app.initialize();

function onDeviceReady(){        

}

function onBackKeyDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: as none of my functions are getting called i cant see why this would be called. problem is more getting it to actually fire the key event

Comment: Your OP states that you received the device ready event. Are you saying that you never receive the "backbuttonpressed" alert? If yes, please edit your OP as it is confusing.

Comment: sry thats my mistake not explaining well enough, im getting the event received but its from some hidden functions.. none of my functions are getting fired, not even onload()

Comment: Edited answer, remove the onload function and try what I typed.

Comment: Eric sry i respond so late, but your code works! guess its because my onLoad never fires and then nothing worked.. But thanks a lot